# Date format in Stata mismatch error

Tags: date, stata

Here is the format of the original date : 01/31/2016 (MDY)

I want to change the format of this date

```
gen date = date(Date, "MDY")  //Date is the varname of my original date

format date %td
```

Error : type mismatch r(109)

Comment: Please read and act on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
clear
set obs 1 
gen Date = "01/31/2016"
gen date = date(Date, "MDY")  //Date is the varname of my original date
format date %td
list 

     +------------------------+
     |       Date        date |
     |------------------------|
  1. | 01/31/2016   31jan2016 |
     +------------------------+
```

so I guess you're doing something different and not telling us about it.

That is,

1. The result of `date()` if it executes without error can only be a numeric variable containing integers.
2. So it will take a daily date format without complaint.

Your error message implies that `date` is string.

If you really tried to `format Date %td`, then that could be the error.

Alternatively, if `Date` is a numeric variable with display format `%tdN/D/Y` so that a numeric date meaning 31 January 2016 would display as `01/31/16` then to change its format you need not and cannot it push it through `date()`: you just change the format with `format Date %td`.

You seem close to the fallacy that display format means storage type.  See [this paper for a refutation of that idea](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0067).